# Deleting rows in R based on values over multiple columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove rows from a dataframe.

I need to remove rows that have **only** "NONE" or white space across the entire range of columns I provide. The rows that need to be removed must satisfy these conditions 1. a combination of only "NONE" and white space or all "NONE" or all white space.

Because there are cases where having "NONE" or white space in some of the columns is okay I can't just filter out rows when reading in the csv with something like

```
dataframe$col1 =="NONE" | str_length(dataframe$col1)==0
```

I know this would normally be a simple problem where I could run a for loop that turns all "NONE" values and whitespace in a dataframe to NA and use `complete.cases` across whichever columns I need ([doc](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/complete.cases.html)). However, I'm specifically being asked to use a method that does not change the values. Any suggestions?

Edit: I don't have the data, but here is a made up example of a dataframe that would be similar to what I have to work with

[image]

In this dataframe the only row that must be removed is row 3 (or row 4 if you include the header).

The final dataset will have many more columns than this made up example

Comment: Replace the `||` with `|`

Comment: Okay I changed it!

Comment: If you want much more help, it would be useful to provide sample data. Can you paste the output from `dput(head(dataframe))` into your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::filter_all()` to accomplish this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(column.1 = c('a', 'b', 'NONE', 'b', 'b'),
                 column.2 = c('a', 'b', '', 'b', 'b'),
                 column.3 = rep('', 5),
                 column.4 = rep('', 5),
                 column.5 = rep('', 5))

df %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(. != 'NONE' & . != ''))
```

Comment: This is exactly it! One last question: how do I apply this to a range of columns in the dataframe like if I only want the filter to check over columns 5 to 60? I'm not saying remove the columns just that the filter will only check columns 5 to 60

Comment: You can use dplyr select helpers: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select_helpers.html filter_at(df, vars(starts_with("column")), any_vars(. != 'NONE' & . != ''))

Comment: If this answer works, please green-check it so others can more easily find it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since the rows with NONE and whitespace need to be removed, it would be:

```
dataframe <- filter(dataframe, col1 != "NONE" & str_length(col1) != 0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work on my example dataframe. If I gave the range of columns with filter like that wouldnt I remove every single row in my example dataframe instead of just row 3 like I want?

Comment: That depends on the data. If column.3 had NONE in row 1 then you would want to delete row 1 and row 3 right? So, If there are NONE and whitespaces in most of the rows when considering all the columns then yes, most of the rows would get deleted.

Comment: No if NONE is in row 1 column 3 I would NOT want to delete row 1 because there is some usable data in column 1 and 2. It's about whether it is ONLY "NONE" or white space in every single one of the columns of that row

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `filter()` command from the dplyr package (part of the tidyverse library). It would look something like this:

`dataframe_new <- filter(dataframe, col1 == "" | str_length(col1) == 0)`

Comment: I think looking at just one column like this wouldn't work because it's about the range of columns and if I gave the range of columns using your method above wouldn't I remove every single row in my example dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

```
is.none <- function(x) tolower(x) == "none"
is.whitespace <- function(x) grepl("^\\s+$", x)
is.empty <- function(x) length(x) == 0 || x == "" || is.na(x) || is.nan(x)
is.none.whitespace.empty <- function(x) is.none(x) || is.whitespace(x) || is.empty(x)

is.none.whitespace.empty <- Vectorize(is.none.whitespace.empty)

remove.empty.rows <- function(df, cols) {
  df[!sapply(1:nrow(df), 
             function(i) all(is.none.whitespace.empty(df[i, cols]))), ]
}
```

Now you can test it:

```
# in your case:
remove.empty.rows(df, 1) # remove if first column content is "empty"

# but you can determine which columns should be examined for being all
# "empty".
# let's say, you want to evaluate only first, third and fifth column:
remove.empty.rows(df, c(1, 3, 5))
```

Comment: Hmm okay I ran this applying `df` to this example data and nothing changed.